# Node modules path to scoped package not found

Tags: node.js, express

Got a pretty simple express.js app. I set some paths for the app views in `server.js` like so:

```
path.join(__dirname, 'app/components'),
path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/frontend/button/')
```

Those paths work fine. However the following does not:

`path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/@npm.username/my-npm-package/'),`

I thought the problem could be the way the `path` package parses dots/periods, "`.`", so I tried with `path.normalize('/node_modules/@npm.username/my-npm-package/')`. But that doesn't help.

Anyone has any ideas/pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `require.resolve`.

Example: `const path=require.resolve('@npm.username/my-npm-package')`

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options